# Timeout when trying to export a mongodb collection via navicat?

Tags: windows, mongodb, ssh, navicat, mongoexport

I'm trying to export a collection using an ssh Navicat connection but I get this timeout message

[The message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6rbS.png)

[Here is my connection configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soAjY.png)

Comment: Try increasing the `keepalive interval` parameter

Comment: I tried it but didn't solve my problem, it still times out

Comment: Are you getting the same error while exporting from CLI using `mongoexport` command?

Comment: I didn't try using CLI, I m working with an ssh connection, how can I use a CLI command?

Comment: I tried MongoDB Compass, the same issue it exports and stops in the middle of the process before completing the export